# Why 2p Orbitals overlap more effectively than 3p orbitals?

Tags: valence-bond-theory

So, for example, looking at HF and HCl, we see that the 1s orbital of the H overlap with the 2p orbital of F more effectively. Which argument can i use to explain that? Density?

Comment: Orbital size and shape, if anything.

Answer (score 2):

As the quantum number increases, the size of the orbital, or more precisely, the area in which electrons are found, increases. The same 1s orbital of H combines with greater overlap with 2p of F,  while the larger 3p of Cl can’t be approached to that extent because of its size. 
For the sake of demonstration, consider a child shaking hand with the other child, which is a full overlap of palms, while a child shaking hand with an adult is not!

Comment: When I make something bigger, the overlap must increase or stay the same. There are other reasons why the overlap is "less effective".